# Laravel 5.5 pass a parameter from a controller to a resource

Tags: php, laravel

I have difficult to figure out how I can pass a parameter from a method in a controller to a resource.

In the web.php I have this route:

```
Route::get('location/{id}','Controller@getLocation');
```

Below the method in a controller class:

```
public function getLocation($id){ 
    $result= //query
    return new LocationResource($result);
}
```

I wanto to pass the `$id` from controller to LocationResource. How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: do you mean you wnat to pass the $id from one controller method to another resource controller?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right, just execute the query to get the object:

```
$result = Location::find($id);
```

In resource you'll have access to this object through `$this`:

```
'id' => $this->id,
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#resource-responses

Comment: But consider that $id  not belong to  the model Location, the Id is an attribute of another Model but I need to pass it from the controller to the model Location...

Comment: @user8958651 just execute the query using this ID. If it's `belongsTo()`, you can do something like `$result = Location::where('some_id', $id)->first();` or `$result = SomeModel::find($id)->location` Also, both objects will be available in `Resource` class. There are examples in the docs.

Comment: @user8958651 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#writing-resources - scroll down to `Relationships`

Comment: ok, but this is the standard approah, but my dubs depends on to create a new attribute in the method toArray that came from the controller...and is external to the current model...

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You should add some safety checks as well:

```
public function getLocation($id){ 
    if ($location = LocationResource::find($id)) {
        return $location;
    }
    abort(404, 'location ' . $id . ' not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not difficult

before first function of your resource `public function toArray($request)`
create a constructor function . know you can use `$this->result`

```
public function __construct($result)
{
    $this->result = $result;
}
```